# I can't figure this syntaxerror

Tags: javascript

So i got this today

```
  [2018-02-11T15:51:38.772] [DEBUG] default - SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Request._callback (/home/bot/site.js:96:16)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/bot/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/bot/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/bot/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
```

I cant figure this out i don't know what happened this is in site js

```
var prices; 
request('http://backpack.tf/api/IGetMarketPrices/v1/?key=58503fc4e338774aec34d9b0&appid=730', function(error, response, body) {
    prices = JSON.parse(body);
    if(prices.response.success == 0) {
        logger.warn('It was not possible to load prices. Prices taken from the cache');
        if(fs.existsSync(__dirname + '/prices.txt')){
            prices = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/var/www/prices.txt'));
            logger.warn('Prices have been retrieved from the cache');
        } else {
            logger.error('No prices in cache');
            process.exit(0);
        }
        if(fs.existsSync(__dirname + '/var/www/prices.txt')){
            prices = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/var/www/prices.txt'));
            logger.warn('/var/www/prices.txt Loaded cached');
        } else {
            logger.error('No /var/www/prices.txt in cache');
            process.exit(0);
        }
    } else {
        fs.writeFileSync('/var/www/prices.txt', body);
        logger.trace('Prices loaded successfully');
    }
});
```

What's wrong with JSON.parse? i have tried to figure this out for a long time this is big bite for newbie i thinkXD

Comment: this is a syntax error in the JSON being passed in, not in the code

Comment: It looks like your response isn’t JSON at all. The < in the first position indicates that you may actually be getting HTML or XML back instead. I’d check that first (maybe hit the HTTP route or something and see what you get back).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse a string that begins with < as JSON but this is not valid JSON.

To debug, check the contents of the body before you parse it.

Comment: Thanks guys for help! I fixed that link and it works!